# Is Math.pow more expensive than multiplication using temporary assignments?

Tags: javascript, exponent

When porting a javascript library to Python, I found this code:

```
return Math.atan2(
    Math.sqrt(
       (_ = cosφ1 * sinΔλ) * _ + (_ = cosφ0 * sinφ1 - sinφ0 * cosφ1 * cosΔλ) * _
    ), 
    sinφ0 * sinφ1 + cosφ0 * cosφ1 * cosΔλ
);
```

Am I wrong or `(_ = cosφ1 * sinΔλ) * _` could be written like `Math.pow(cosφ1 * sinΔλ, 2)`?

I guess the author is trying to avoid using Math.pow, is this expensive in javascript compared to the temporary assignment?

[update]

As of late 2016, with Chrome 53.0 (64-bit) looks like the difference is not as large as it used to be.

Comment: Why dont you try it out at [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) and let us know.

Comment: @atomman: nice to know about jsperf, thanks

Comment: http://jsben.ch/#/lhQpz check it here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is performance. First let's test if they actually do the same and we didn't overlook something.

```
var test = (test = 5 * 2) * test; // 100
Math.pow(5 * 2, 2); // 100
```

As expected, that's proven to do the same. Now let's see if they have different performances using jsperf. Check it out here: [http://jsperf.com/...num-self](http://jsperf.com/math-pow-num-2-vs-self-num-self)

The differences for Firefox 23 are *very* small, but for Safari the difference was much bigger. Using `Math.pow` seems to be more expensive there.

Comment: Nice to know jsperf, I had no clue on how to profile javascript. The legibility sacrifice may be worth since it is from a distance function that will be applied to potentially lengthy arrays.

Comment: @PauloScardine If you plan to use it a lot, screw the legibility. You can always add comments to explain what that line of code does. I had to read it a couple of times before I got it.

Comment: This code is from Mike Bostock of D3 fame, it is way beyond my wizardry level. Thanks for the answer. :-)

Comment: How does this compare to `exp` ?